# webcam streaming using python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tcp

I'm having a idea of using TCP socket to send array object captured by webcam to a client and reconstruct the image in another program.

Server Side:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import cv2
UDP_IP = '192.168.1.3'
UDP_PORT = 8081
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
sock.listen(1)

conn,addr=sock.accept()
print(addr)
while(True):
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   cv2.imshow('streamer',frame)
   conn.send(frame.toBytes)
   print(frame)
```

Client side:

```
import socket
import numpy
import time
import cv2

UDP_IP="192.168.1.3"
UDP_PORT = 8081
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))


while True:
      data = sock.recv(480*640*3)
      print(data)
```

my issue is in server side the array is showing up correctly in the console. But in the client side the console is filled with Junk characters.
Why is that.? How should i reconstruct the array same as the server side?

Comment: How do you know it is not part of one frame and part of another? maybe you can send some start frame, end frame bytes to know where the byte array starts/end? also the receiving data should be casted to numpy.uint8 in case it is not yet that (probably byte array or characters)

Comment: I have answered to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084143/opencv-live-stream-video-over-socket-in-python-3/63717263#63717263